# Open Powershell Here not working with folders containing punctuation marks

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I've been recently encountering some issues with Powershell not willing to open in certain folders that had punctuation marks in the name.
This is way I'm looking for a way to modify the registry key responsible for this behavior.
This is the actual error message I receive when opening PS in one of these folders:
`Powershell Script is missing the Terminator '`

And this is my command line so far:
`powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'`

So I thought that maybe this was an encoding issue and tried launching powershell with UTF-8 encoding by modifying the registry key to this:
`powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'; "chcp.com 65001"`

Which was not very successful... I don't know if my though process is right, that's why I'm asking you to help me figure out the problem and If it can be solved.

NB: I still can manually browse the folder without modifying the encoding in PS.

Comment: So what is the folder name?

Comment: Anything that has an apostrophe in its name as stated above. Take ```Mom's spaghetti``` as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is a string termination character in PS, so, it's working as designed.

Meaning reading, up to the character and stopping. So, not an encoding error.

Since the Open PowerShell Here, is just pulling in the dir name and anything with  terminating characters, need to be directly handled, and of course there is no out of box way to do this with that config.

Please note, that this is not an error with Open PowerShell Here, as if you did this the normal way in Windows Explorer...

- Open explorer
- navigate to the folder
- Press Alt, F, and select Open With PowerShell
- or click the PowerShell icon in the toolbar

... the same thing will happen.

You need to remove the characters that are string terminators from you folder names

If you are doing this in code, then you must enclose that folder in double quotes.

See the help docs for …

> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6